# Is it okay to travel in China with temporary residence permit form?

Tags: visas, china, domestic-travel

My passport is currently being held in the Exit-Entry Administration Bureau in Shenzhen as I’m applying for a Chinese residence permit extension. They gave me a stamped “temporary residence permit form” and when I asked if I can use the form to travel to other cities they said okay. However, when I asked my university staff to contact the police, they have different opinions, saying that different cities may have different policies. So, my question is has anyone had the experience of traveling to any city in China with just the photocopy of the passport or the temporary residence permit form? I am planning to go to Zhangjiajie from Shenzhen this month and I’m just not sure if this would work.

Any kind of guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How well is your conversational Chinese?

Comment: @xuq01 Decent I guess. I have excellent listening skills though. How is that relevant?

Comment: If your Chinese skills are good, you can kindly explain to your hotel that the police told you the document is OK for travel and ask them to verify with the local police station if they have doubts about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is valid for domestic travel. According to China Southern Air website:

> According to the relevant regulations of the Ministry of Transport and
>   the Civil Aviation Administration of China, valid ID documents for
>   traveling include: Resident ID cards, **temporary resident ID cards**,
>   passports, certificates of military officer, certificates of PLA
>   civilian cadre, certificates of compulsory serviceman, certificates of
>   PLA sergeant, certificates of PLA civil service, certificates of PLA
>   employee, certificates of PAP officer, certificates of PAP soldier,
>   seafarer's passports for residents in Chinese mainland; Mainland
>   Travel Permit for Hong Kong and Macao Residents, Mainland Travel
>   Permit for Taiwan Residents, and residence permits for Hong Kong,
>   Macao and Taiwan residents; passports, certificates of diplomatic
>   staff in China issued by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs, and
>   permanent residence (identity) certificates for foreigners; other
>   valid ID documents for traveling as stipulated by the Civil Aviation
>   Administration of China. For residents in Chinese mainland under the
>   age of 16, valid ID documents for traveling also include birth
>   certificates, household registers, student ID cards or identity
>   certificates issued by the public security organ at the place where
>   residence is registered.

https://www.csair.com/en/orders/order/lxzjtx/

Comment: Yes this is correct for all forms of domestic travel

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information. I ended up calling Zhangjiajie and Shenzhen airports, and confirmed with them that traveling with a police-approved temporary residence permit form is permitted.

Answer (score -5):

You should have original passport

Comment: Passport is not needed for domestic travel.

Comment: This is not true, the temporary paper is sufficient for domestic travel